# c# : Close chromium browsers without close google chrome browsers

Tags: c#, .net, process, chromium

I would like to close [chromium](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(navigateur_web)) web  processs

[image]

without closing [google  chrome](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) browser which are running

[image]

The code bellow close chromium browsers but also google chrome browsers, that I don't want to :

```
 var chromeAndChomiumProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
 foreach (var chromeAndChomiumProcess in chromeAndChomiumProcesses)
 {
        chromeAndChomiumProcess.Kill();
 }
```

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: IF you kill the process, the application will close.

Comment: the tricky here is to kill chromium but no chrome @RyanWilson

Comment: So you want to kill off any Google processes that are not the browser?

Comment: I want to kill chromium web browsers  https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium but no google  chrome web browsers https://www.google.com/chrome/

Comment: seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to kill it, and does the process have anything distinguishing in the windows task manager .. like command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work if you know the path to Chromium. Plus, You will have to compile the code as x64.

```
Process[] chrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

foreach (var chromeProcess in chrome)
{
    string fullPath = chromeProcess.MainModule.FileName;
    string expectedPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

    if (fullPath.Equals(expectedPath))
    {
        chromeProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind this comparison needs to be case sensitive.